# PostgreSQL: how to create a trigger that runs after adding a new row in one table and rows related in another table?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, one-to-many

I have two tables, e.g. TABLE1, TABLE2. They are joined by "one-to-many" relationship (many records from TABLE2 are referencing to every record in TABLE1). I want to make a trigger that runs just after adding a new row in TABLE1 and all the rows related with it in TABLE2. How to solve it? In particular, how to "inform" the trigger that all related rows from TABLE2 are added?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself yet? If no start with that manual page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: I have solved the problem. I used a transaction which encompassed both adding a row in TABLE1 and adding rows in TABLE2. It suffices for my purpose.